# PHP check if array contains start of string

Tags: php

How can I check if the *start* of a given value matches an entry in a predefined list of values?

```
$model_no1 = "KK71458";
$model_no2 = "IX41";

$models = array("KK61", "KK71", "KK81", "IX", "IJ");
```

In the above sample code, both values should return a valid match.

Comment: Whats your input (x number of strings, one string)?
How should your output look?

Comment: How large arrays and strings do you want to be able to process? Naive solutions to this would be very inefficient for large arrays/strings.

Comment: Just one string. The array will contain no more than a hundred entries similar to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$model_no1 = "KK71458";
    $models = array("KK61", "KK71", "KK81", "IX", "IJ");
    foreach($models as $key=> $mod){
        if($mod == substr($model_no1,0,strlen($mod))){ 
            echo "key: ".$key.' with value: '.$mod;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function rather than combination of `substr()` and `strlen()` in your case:

```
$model_no1 = 'KK71458';
$model_no2 = 'IX41';

$models = array('KK61', 'KK71', 'KK81', 'IX', 'IJ');
$result1 = check_model($model_no1, $models);
$result2 = check_model($model_no2, $models);

function check_model($model_no, array $models) {
    foreach ($models as $needle) {
        if (0 === strpos($model_no, $needle))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I wrote the simple [test](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/StrposVsStrstr.php) for checking string comparison performance by `strpos()`, `strstr()` and `substr()+strlen()`. Here is results:

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
strpos          10000           0.167221 sec    +0.00%
strstr          10000           0.169299 sec    -1.24%
substr+strlen   10000           0.207363 sec    -24.01%
```

As you see `strpos()` has best performance results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$models = array("KK61", "KK71", "KK81", "IX", "IJ");

$g = function($search) use ($models) {
    return array_filter($models, function($string) use($search) {
        return substr($search, 0, strlen($string)) == $string;
    });
};

print_r($g->__invoke('KK71458'));
print_r($g->__invoke('IX41'));
print_r($g->__invoke('SPONGEBOB'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HarryIsBack has reversed $mod and $model_no1.

Correct like this :

$model_no1 = "KK71458";
    $models = array("KK61", "KK71", "KK81", "IX", "IJ");
    foreach($models as $key=> $mod){
        if($model_no1 == substr($mod,0,strlen($model_no1))){ 
            echo "key: ".$key.' with value: '.$mod;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).